# Excel formula . Find something over a listing of dates for each person

Tags: arrays, excel, function, excel-formula

I've been trying to resolve this all day. In my data have a list of names, each person have many dates listed, with a "acceptable" or "not acceptable" for each date. What I'm looking for is the "not acceptable" when listed at the latest date for each person .

The picture show a small example of my data. 
Is anyone able to help me with it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have `MAXIFS()`? Also, those dates, are they actual dates? Or text values looking like dates?

Comment: Hi. Yes those are dates

Comment: Then, if you do have `MAXIFS` it's not too hard. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the Maxifs() . What I tried if the (max for the dates, than the if() for find the word "not acceptable". But I can't apply it based on people's names. In my data I have like 800 names to go through, all with different dates.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Another option could be a pivot table in your case then

Comment: I tried , but the result gave me the " not acceptable " for every date for each person, instead of the latest date only.

Comment: This is why I asked if your data is not text looking like dates, cause I'm a 99% sure they are.

Answer (score 0):

In excel.. do :

```
=DATEVALUE(B1) in D1
```

then drag in downwards..

select all 4 columns. Data > filter . then sort the data by date. You should get your result up to this step..

Note : formula cannot work if the raw data is not clean.. (take a look at line 6 & 7, different spelling bob is there...)

hope it helps..